# GTM Event: How do I get the label text for checkbox clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a form which I want to use Google tag manager to get the label text as an event label when someone clicks on the checkbox. I was able to get it to work when a user clicks on the actual label, but doesn't work when the user click on the checkbox rather than the label.

What I am trying to do is to get the text located by the side of the check box. from the example HTML code of the checkbox (pasted below), you can see both the checkbox and text are inside the  tag and I need to get the text located next to the checkbox.

`code`

```
<div class="stockist-search-filter-checkboxes">
<div class="stockist-search-filter-checkbox">
<label>
<input name="filters" type="checkbox" value="11222">Home Specialist
</label>
</div>
</div>
```

`code`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can change a selector to catch the checkbox click rather than the label click. Or you can add an event listener to the checkbox on page load and send a dataLayer event from it for GTM to fire your event.

If this is not enough for you to resolve it, show your html around the checkbox (NOT as a screenshot) and show how you configured the trigger (as a screenshot).

Here's a code sample for adding a listener that pushes the DL event on checkbox changes.

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=checkbox]");

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
  dataLayer.push({
    event:"checkbox_changed",
    checkboxIsChecked: checkbox.checked,
    checkboxName: checkbox.getAttribute("name")
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks @BNazaruk for your suggestion. Please can you provide a sample code for an event listener listening to the check box for when it gets checked, then sending a dataLayer event from GTM? At the moment I'm using the in-built variables to handle the sending of label text when the checkbox label is clicked.
Here's the HTML for the checkbox

<div class="stockist-search-filter-checkboxes"><div class="stockist-search-filter-checkbox"><label><input name="filters" type="checkbox" value="11222">Home Specialist</label></div></div>

Comment: I added a code example for a normal checkbox. Use it if you can. If you can't, then add the html just like I said. Not in the comment. Edit your original question. Or ask a new one with adequate details.

Comment: Thanks @BNazaruk . What I am trying to do is to get the text located by the side of the check box. The code you provided gets the name of the checkbox.  from the example code of the check box (repasted below), both the checkbox and text are inside the <label> tag and I need to get the text located next to the checkbox
'code' 
<div class="stockist-search-filter-checkboxes">
<div class="stockist-search-filter-checkbox">
<label>
<input name="filters" type="checkbox" value="11222">Home Specialist
</label>
</div></div>
'code'

Comment: add screenshots of what you need exactly, how it looks and code around it.

Answer (score 0):

I was just running into this same issue/need!

My checkboxes look like this:

```
<div class="ginput_container ginput_container_checkbox">
    <div class="gfield_checkbox" id="input_1_20">
        <div class="gchoice gchoice_1_20_1">
            <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.1" type="checkbox" value="breakfast-pattie" id="choice_1_20_1">
            <label for="choice_1_20_1" id="label_1_20_1" class="gform-field-label gform-field-label--type-inline">Label Text Here</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(thanks for the code bloat, Gravity Forms)

This is the JS that is working well for me to accomplish what I think you're asking!

```
<script>
  var theAssociatedLabel,elementID;     
  var thisElement = event.target;
  elementID = thisElement.id;      
  theAssociatedLabel = thisElement.parentNode.querySelector("label[for='" + elementID + "']");         

  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'element_toggled',
    'elementLabel': theAssociatedLabel.innerHTML
  });
</script>
```

I'm not a JS-pro, so I know it could probably be improved but works well enough for now!

I use a Custom Event trigger to get the ID, value (auto-event variable), and the label (data-layer variable) to pull through.

This is a good resource to understand all of that, too -- https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/datalayer-push/

Comment: any affiliation to that blog? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: No affiliation at all, I just found it helpful  in the process.